# Second click doesnt work before takeUntil

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm making a drag and drop, when I drag a block and drop then second time I cant drag it again how can I fix it please take a look the part of snippeds bellow.

```
  dragTask(blocks: HTMLElement): void {
      fromEvent(blocks, 'mousedown')
        .pipe(
          exhaustMap(() =>
            fromEvent(this.board.nativeElement, 'mousemove').pipe(
              takeUntil(this.mouseOutSubject$),// I cant remove this part becouse when i remove this part the block is always been takken
              finalize(()=>{
                this.mouseOutSubject$.next(false);
                console.log(this.mouseOutSubject$)
              })
            )
          )
        ).subscribe((event: MouseEvent | any) => {
        this.detectMouseUp(blocks);
        this.board.nativeElement.append(blocks);
        blocks.setAttribute('style',`
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          transform:translate3d(${event.pageX - 250}px, ${event.pageY - 100}px,0);
      `)
      })
  }
```

**Detect mouseup**

```
  detectMouseUp(block: HTMLElement): void {
    fromEvent(block, 'mouseup').pipe(
      takeUntil(this.mouseOutSubject$)
    ).subscribe((res: MouseEvent | any) => {
      this.mouseOutSubject$.next(true);
  }
```

Comment: Can you maybe create a stackblitz example for us to see the actual issue?

Comment: the project is so big i cant create it in stackblitz